# Who originally speculated that the Orchos Tzaddikim's author was a woman?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, authorship

I recall hearing (as well as saw from [this link](http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/53259-who-wrote-the-orchos-tzaddikim/)) that it has been speculated that the author of the [Orchos Tzaddikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim,_Introduction?lang=bi) was a woman.

Did someone originally posit this idea, or is it a rumor that has been passed around?

Comment: From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchot_Tzaddikim): "There is speculation that the book was authored by a female, owing to the author's heavy reliance on biblical passages as sources and choosing to publish anonymously, though publishing anonymously may merely indicate the author's very example of character development." Apparently, the Yiddish "translation" is older than the Hebrew "original" too. Judging that Yiddish began as a woman's language (Wieber-Teitsch), it might be a good hypthothis.

Comment: @ezra but who made such a claim? Also,  just because of those reasons doesn't make a good hypothesis.

Comment: Hence my use of the word "might". I haven't been able to track down a source. It seems to just be a rumor by mouth from those who have read the book. In all honesty, the anonymity of the author is probably just a reflection of the book's contents... Probably an act of humility on part of the author, similar to how the Chofetz Chaim published anonymously.

Comment: @ezra Vaybertaytsh refers to a particular script used for writing Yiddish for women, not to the language itself. I don't know why you think Yiddish originated as a women's language.

Comment: @magicker72 I read it in the book _The Jews of Germany: A Historical Portrait_ by Peter and Ruth Gay.

Comment: @ezra on page 14 of that book, it says that the audience for popular Yiddish books was mainly women, not that it was a women's language. It says that explicitly on page 16, along with the definition of vaybertaytsh as a script.

Comment: @magicker72 It has been a while since I've read the book; thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Hi, guy who made the comment in the linked text there. Dr Alan Morinis, founder of The Mussar Institute showed me an article; but this many years later I can't recall more details. There were two primary arguments for this suggestion: Others mentioned the language the original was thought to be written in -- Yiddish. Another is that the book makes heavy use of quotes, but quotes from the Mishnah or Talmud are all well-known texts. Which would fit authorship by someone who wasn't encouraged to learn such sources.

Comment: HOWEVER, with the discovery of the Warsaw 1430 manuscript of Seifer haMiddos (the book's original name) in Hebrew, much of the wind was taken out of the sales of that theory.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi , i do not know what you are asking.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi - what are you asking about? If half the reason for theorizing that the author could have been a woman was that the book was written in Yiddish, and now the evidence points to it having been originally in Hebrew with an early translation to Yiddish, that speculation gets shakier. But I said that much already; I just don't know what your "pardon" means.

Comment: @MichaBerger nevermind my question. I highly doubt the speculation that the Orchos HaTzaddikim was written by a woman after having gone further in it as there is a decent amount of Shass in the Sefer based on what I have learned.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi The other piece pf evidence (other than the belief at the time that the oldest version was in Yoddish)was which gemaros. It seems nearly all the quotes of shas and rishonim are ones quoted in commentaries on Tanach and in then oft-quoted works. As though these author's exposure to these works were aecond hand.